# non-abelian groups of order of product of 3 distinct primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Suppose that $p,q,r$ are distinct primes such that

$q = 1 \pmod p$

$pq = 1 \pmod r$

Consider the following group $G$ of order $pqr$:

$1$ element must be the identity element

Exactly $q-1$ elements are of order $q$.

Exactly $q(p-1)$ elements are of order $p$.

Exactly $pq(r-1)$ elements are of order $r$.

These fit the criteria of the Sylow theorems, so a group with this given structure seems possible.

From the first two criteria, we would need to have a non-abelian subgroup of order $pq$. The rest of the elements not in this subgroup are of order $r$. If we have one element, say $g$ of order $r$, we can generate the rest of them in the following way:

$\langle g \rangle = \{1, g, g^2, g^3, ... g^{r-1}\}$. This is one of the subgroups of order $r$. For every element of the $h$ non-abelian subgroup of order $pq$, $gh$ will be an element of order $r$, and will generate exactly one subgroup of order $r$.

The group presentation is given by $\langle α, β, γ: α^p, β^q, γ^r, (αβ)^{p}, (αβγ)^{r} \rangle$

More generally, consider the product $$n = \prod_{i=0}^{k} a_i$$ where all $a_i$ are mutually coprime and

$a_j = 1 \pmod {\prod_{i=0}^{j-1} a_i}$

for $j > 0$.

Then there exists a group $G$ with order $n$ such that:

There is an identity element.

A subgroup of order $a_0$.

$a_{j}$ subgroups of order $a_{j+1}$.

Are these group structures and presentations (described above) valid (as well as the general case involving mutually coprime group orders)? Why or why not?

Comment: You say, "the following group structures" at the *end* of the question, where no group structures follow.

Comment: My bad. I mean the group structures I described earlier in the question.

Answer (score 3):

No, such a group cannot exist.

The fact that there are $q-1$ elements of order $q$ implies that $G$ has a normal Sylow $q$-subgroup $Q$.
Let $C$ be the centraliser of $Q$ in $G$. We have $Q\leq C$.
If $C=Q$, then, by the "N/C Theorem", $G/Q$ embeds into $\mathrm{Aut}(Q)$, which is abelian (as $Q$ is cyclic). So $G/Q$ is abelian and thus should contain elements of order $pr$, a contradiction.
If $C>Q$ then $Q$ must commute with some element of order $p$ or $r$ and $G$ should have elements of order $qp$ or $qr$ again a contradiction.

More generally, groups of squarefree order admit a nice classification. In particular, they are always metacyclic.